# C++ Expected string literal before args

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string argstr[argc];
    for(int c = 1; c++; c<argc) {
        argstr[c].assign(argv[c]);
    }

    for(int c = 1; c++; c<argc) {
        __asm__(argstr[c]); //This is where the error occurs
        cout << argstr[c] << endl;
    }
}
```

If I try to compile it with MinGW, I get the following error:

```
    Main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
    Main.cpp:15:6: error: expected string-literal before 'args'
      asm(args);
```

I know this, that's why I assign the arguments to a vector of strings.

Comment: A std::string is not a string literal.

Comment: A string literal is a string whose value is represented in the source code as characters enclosed in quotes, `"like this"`. It's impossible to assemble anything at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

`__asm__()` is a *compile-time* construct. The argument *must* be a string literal, and not a variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can't dynamically execute assembly code like this. The compiler needs to know about the assembly instructions at compile time so it can check if they are valid, but you are trying to pass them in at run time.

Edit: One workaround is to write a wrapper program in python (for example) that injects a string literal into your C++ `__asm__` construct and then compiles it and executes it for you.

Comment: That is a horrific workaround, please don't do that.